# How to implement List item in TabLayout With ViewPager2

Tags: android, android-tablayout, android-viewpager2

I'm new in Android Development, I'm currently learning in TabLayout with Viewpager2.
I have hardcoded the Fragments in my adapter. Btw I need to add all of my Fragment with list. So how can I add Fragment in list, or Arraylist. Please Help me.

Here is the adapter code:

```java
    public class ScreenSliderAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter{

    public ScreenSliderAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fragmentManager, @NonNull Lifecycle lifecycle) {
        super(fragmentManager, lifecycle);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment createFragment(int position) {

        if (position==0) {

            return new BangladeshFragment();

        } else if (position==1) {

            return new BrazilFragment();

        } else if (position==2) {

            return new MaltaFragment();

        }

        return new BangladeshFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return 3;
    }
}
```

Here is Main Activity Code:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    FragmentManager fm;
    ScreenSliderAdapter sa;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        sa = new ScreenSliderAdapter(fm,getLifecycle());

        ViewPager2 pager = findViewById(R.id.pager);

        TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabLayoutID);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Bangladesh"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Brazil"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Malta"));

        pager.setAdapter(sa);


        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                pager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });


        pager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                tabLayout.selectTab(tabLayout.getTabAt(position));
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Activity**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ViewPager2 myViewPager2;
    MyAdapter MyAdapter;
    private ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        myViewPager2 = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

        arrayList.add("Item 1");
        arrayList.add("Item 2");
        arrayList.add("Item 3");
        arrayList.add("Item 4");
        arrayList.add("Item 5");

        MyAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, arrayList);


        myViewPager2.setOrientation(ViewPager2.ORIENTATION_VERTICAL);

        myViewPager2.setAdapter(MyAdapter);
    }
}
```

**New Features**

```
myViewPager2.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            super.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            super.onPageSelected(position);

            Log.e("Selected_Page", String.valueOf(position));
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            super.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);
        }
    });
```

**MyAdapter**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> arrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.tvName.setText(arrayList.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView tvName;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, I created the project in java, btw your solution is Cotlin based. Can you help me with java code.

Comment: it's not working. can you show me Adapter code?